# Linking to a place further forward

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links

I know how to make a link to an URL or to a place further *backward* in a LaTeX document using the `hyperref` package. However, if I wish to redirect readers to a place further *forward* in the document, I fear the `\hypertarget` or `\label` will not be found. Am I wrong in this expectation? If not, is there a way to achieve such a link?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: This is precisely what the table of contents linking does, which is standard behavior with `hyperref`...

Comment: `label` `ref` supports forward and backward references (with or without hyperref)

Comment: If you'd prepared a MWE for this question (as you should ;) ), you wouldn't have needed to ask it...

Comment: To clarify: the linking mechanism of LaTeX `\label`/`\ref`, and its `hyperref` version, work regardless of the relative positions of the label and reference command.  This is one of the central powers of the construct.

Comment: You have to run `pdflatex` (or latex, xelatex,lualatex) twice such a label coming later on is known in previous sections of the document while the second run is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 'MWE' in the sense that it shows that labels coming later on a in document can be referred to at previous positions in the document.

It shows, that `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` work as well.

Compile twice with one of the latex executables (preferably pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}


\section{First}

In \ref{section::first_sub} we will see that...

\hyperlink{dummytarget}{Click me}
\blindtext[20]



\section{Second}

\subsection{First sub of second section} \label{section::first_sub}
\blindtext[5]


\hypertarget{dummytarget}{Here is a dummy link target}


\end{document}
```